# remove http-equiv="refresh" via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe, http-equiv

so I got a problem I`ve got a HTML Page which is generated by a programm (So not possibly to change it by hand). This got the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; URL=subst_001.htm">
```

Because of this the iframe in which I embed it, keeps reloading after 4 seconds which breaks my javascript code I would have normally used to display it. Any Ideas of removing it via Javascript, or any other way would be highly appreciated.

Have a nice day

Didn´t found a solution on google so hoppefully somebody has a Idea

Comment: try not requesting the pate with '<meta ' directly, write a small JS proxy that will request the page, remove the <meta string and then display the page.

Comment: What program do you use?

Comment: Better go with a reverse proxy server (like nginx) to delegate the access of that page, and modify the content of it on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, although I have not tested this code. You may need to edit this code to make it work.

This approach will only work if the iFrame and the host page both on the same domain.

```
function removeMetaRefresh(){
  const theMetaTag = document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="refresh"]');
  theMetaTag.remove();
}

const theFrame = document.querySelector('iframe');
theFrame.contentWindow.myFunction = removeMetaRefresh;
theFrame.contentWindow.myFunction();
```